# Role based access control in Flask with multiple embedded Dash applications

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, rbac

This has been crushing my skull for the past week. I'd like to be able to restrict access to Dash applications within a Flask application based on the user's role. I used the [flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) as a guide to create this application and used [this guide](https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/) to embed the dash apps within. I created conditional statements in my index.html template to control the links a user sees upon logging in that are relevant to their role:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
<h1>Hi, {{ current_user.username }}!</h1>
<h2>
    My Dashboards
</h2>
{% if current_user.role == 'Department Head' %}
<a href="/laborcosts" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Labor Costs</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/dtidpriority" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>DTID Priority</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/auditreturnreport" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Audit Return Report</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/automationerrorreport" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Automation Error Report</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/clientvolume" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Client Volume</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/outofscope" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Out Of Scope</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/teamlevelpoints" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Team Level Points</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/userlevelpoints" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>User Level Points</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/usererrorreport" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>User Error Report</span>
</a>
{% endif %}
{% if current_user.role == 'Team Lead' %}
<a href="/auditreturnreport" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Audit Return Report</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/automationerrorreport" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Automation Error Report</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/clientvolume" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Client Volume</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/outofscope" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Out Of Scope</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/teamlevelpoints" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>Team Level Points</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/userlevelpoints" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>User Level Points</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="/usererrorreport" class="dash-link" target="_blank">
    <span>User Error Report</span>
</a>
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

which is kind of a work around to the issue. However, if a user were to just enter the route to any of the embedded dash applications in the address bar, they'd be able to access the dashboard regardless of their role. This is what I'm trying to restrict. I've looked into Flask-Authorize, Flask-Principal, and Flask-RBAC, but found nearly all their documentation to be cryptic at best. At the very least, I'm not able to understand the proper way to implement those solutions in my specific instance. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

*models.py*

```py
import jwt
from time import time
from flask import current_app
from landing_page_pkg import db, login
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from landing_page_pkg import login
from flask_security import RoleMixin

class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    role = db.Column(db.String(64))
    pin = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User {self.username}>'
    
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def get_reset_password_token(self, expires_in=600):
        return jwt.encode(
            {'reset_password': self.id, 'exp': time() + expires_in},
            current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm='HS256')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_password_token(token):
        try:
            id = jwt.decode(token, current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
                            algorithms=['HS256'])['reset_password']
        except:
            return
        return User.query.get(id)    

    
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

*forms.py*

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, RadioField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, ValidationError,Email,EqualTo
from landing_page_pkg.models import User

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')
    
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    ### NOTICE: To get the label to show for the "Role" field using wtf.quickform
    ### you must edit flask-bootstrap/templates/wtf.html and add {{field.label(class="control-label")|safe}}
    ### BEFORE the for loop {% for item in field -%}
    ###                       <div class="radio">
    role = RadioField(label='Role',choices=['Department Head','Team Lead','Project Manager'],validators=[DataRequired()])
    pin = IntegerField(label='Access Code')
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
        
    def validate_role(self,role,pin):
        roles = role.data
        pins = pin.data
        
        if pins != 1000 and roles == 'Department Head':
            raise ValidationError('This role requires the proper Access Code. Please contact Seymour Stats administration for access.')        
        elif pins != 2000 and roles == 'Team Lead':
            raise ValidationError('This role requires the proper Access Code. Please contact Seymour Stats administration for access.')    
        
class ResetPasswordRequestForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    submit = SubmitField('Request Password Reset')
    
class ResetPasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Request Password Reset')
```

Please let me know if there's more code I can provide to help out.

## **UPDATE**

I was able to solve my issue by initializing flask-principal inside of my dash app and restricting access to specific roles for callbacks. I created a callback to update the layout based on access as well, so that an unauthorized user can only see an error message, while an authorized user can see the full dashboard.

```py
 @app.callback(
        Output('layout_content','children'),
        Input('url','pathname')
    )
    def dh_layout(pathname):
        #### app layout ####

        #unauthorized message
                if not access_permission.can():
            unauthorized_layout = html.Div(
                [
                    html.H1(
                        'Unauthorized Access'
                    ),
                    
                    html.Br(),
                    
                    html.P(
                        'You are not authorized to view this page. If you feel this is an error, please contact administration'
                    )
                ]
            )
            
            return unauthorized_layout

        return app_layout
```

Comment: You need to check directly on your routes, by getting current loggedin user and check the role

Comment: @Christoph the thing is, the way i built the dash applications into flask didn't require creating routes for them. so i'm at a loss here.

Comment: checkout this article: https://dev.to/naderelshehabi/securing-plotly-dash-using-flask-login-4ia2

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question. in fact, the answer to my question is explicitly left out of that article.

Comment: Try my Code below